# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Pruning at selector "widget" from : Ionic

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I try to run the command `ionic cordova run android` I getting errors as 
`> cordova run android
(node:5304) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Pruning at selector "widget" from "D:\project-1\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml" went bad.
    at ConfigFile_prune_child [as prune_child] (D:\project-1\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ConfigChanges\ConfigFile.js:157:15)
    at PlatformMunger_apply_file_munge [as apply_file_munge] (D:\project-1\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ConfigChanges\ConfigChanges.js:80:41)
    at PlatformMunger.remove_plugin_changes (D:\project-1\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ConfigChanges\ConfigChanges.js:106:14)
    at D:\project-1\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\PluginManager.js:126:29
    at _fulfilled (D:\project-1\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (D:\project-1\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\project-1\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
    at D:\project-1\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:877:14
    at runSingle (D:\project-1\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (D:\project-1\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
(node:5304) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5304) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps.**

1. Remove all platforms.

`rm -rf platforms`

2. Remove all plugins.

`rm -rf plugins`

3. Update `Cordova`.

`sudo npm update -g cordova`

4. Add platforms again.

`ionic cordova platform add android`

`ionic cordova platform add ios`

5. Run app

`ionic cordova run android`